# Looking for the weakest possible conditions to add to $|X_n/n|$ being $L^1$ convergent so that I can deduce that $X_n$ is convergent in probability.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Basically, I'm working on some probability assumptions and my goal is to prove the convergence in probability of $X_n$, as of now I could succeed in proving the $L^1$ Convergence of $|X_n/n|$, so I was wondering if there were any extra conditions that I could maybe allow myself to additionally assume to deduce the convergence in probability from that.

Comment: $L^{1}$ convergence of $\frac {X_n} n$ doesn't help much in proving convergence in probability of $(X_n)$. If $(X_n)$ is uniformly bounded then we have  convergence in $L^{1}$  of $\frac {X_n} n$ but this obviously allows  $(X_n)$ to oscillate.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks for your comment! I've got one more question if you don't mind, would $\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}}, \, 0<p<1$ instead of simply $\frac{X_n}{n}$ change anything?

Comment: No, that doesn't help either.